# Wrapping GTK+ functions

Tags: c, gtk

The program is written is C, and the GUI is created by GTK+. There is no problem with algorithms or what, I'm just not sure abut one thing.

I'm planning to wrap some GTK functions, so I can save a lot of source lines of code. For example:

```
GtkWidget *gtkwrap_label_markup_new(const gchar *txt)
{
    GtkWidget *label;

    g_assert(txt);

    label = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), txt);

    return label;
}
```

I use text modified by pango a lot of times, and this wrapper function saved a lot of lines of code. Maybe it's not bad, but what if some other programer would read my code one day, what would be the reaction? "....gtkwrap_label_markup_new? What?!"

I just want to know, if it's within standard to wrap those functions. I don't wanna look like an idiot, and I also don't wanna learn some bad habits. ;)

Comment: I think this question may be more appropriate on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with introducing function to avoid code duplication. In fact, I'd say it is the exact opposite, introducing abstraction helps you develop your code faster, and reduce the cost of fixing issue or changing design.

Comment: Agreed. You just should be sure not to name the functions starting with `gtk_` or somebody may spend a lot of time searching for its non-existent documentation. But the OP is already doing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look to the GTK code if you're in doubt. For example, for [gtk_label_set_markup](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtklabel.c#n2614), you see the case when the str variable is NULL is handled. So putting an assertion to check for that may be appropriate to your application, but I think it's a bit overkill. If you want to be warned, you may prefer `g_return_val_if_fail(str != NULL, NULL)` to return NULL and print a warning if `txt` is NULL.

But if you really want to save a bunch of lines of code, use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) to design your UI, instead of constructing it in plain C.